# Understanding generics: Incompatible types when class has generic type and implements one of its parametrised superclass

Tags: java, android, generics, types, casting

I am implementing a simple app with MVP architecture.

Here are my `MvpView` and `MvpPresenter` interfaces (nothing interesting about `MvpModel`, so I am skipping it):

```
/// MvpView.java
public interface MvpView {
}

/// MvpPresenter.java
public interface MvpPresenter<V extends MvpView> {
    void attachView(V view);

    void detachView();
}
```

Now I have a basic `MvpView` implementation, which is an `Activity`:

```
// BaseActivity.java
public abstract class BaseActivity<V extends MvpView, P extends MvpPresenter<V>> 
        extends AppCompatActivity implements MvpView {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getPresenter().attachView(this);
    }

    public abstract P getPresenter();

    // other logic
}
```

As for me everything looks correct, but **there is a compile error in line:**

```
    getPresenter().attachView(this);
```

[image: incompatible types]

If I add cast to `V` then project compiles and everything works fine:

```
    getPresenter().attachView((V) this);
```

### 1. The question is **why I need this cast** or **why I am experiencing this incompatible types error without casting?**

(1 is already answered by [Eran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45056432/2308720))

### 2. How I can link `V` to `BaseActivity` in this example or how it is better to implement this MVP approach?

It is strange, as for me, because my `BaseActivity` is extending `MvpView` as it is defined by this generic parameter: `V extends MvpView`!

Answer (score 1):

`getPresenter()` is an instance of type `P`, which extends `MvpPresenter<V>`. Therefore `getPresenter.attachView()` expects an argument of type `V`.

Now, we know that `V` must implement `MvpView`, and we also know that `BaseActivity` implements `MvpView`, but this implementations don't necessarily match.

For example, you can create a concrete sub-class `SubBaseActivity` and instantiate it with:

```
SubBaseActivity<MvpViewImpl, MvpPresenterImpl<MvpViewImpl>>
    activity = new SubBaseActivity<> (); // let's ignore the fact that you are not suppose
                                         // to instantiate Android activities this way
```

Now `getPresenter()` returns a `MvpPresenterImpl` and `getPresenter().attachView()` expects an argument of type `MvpViewImpl`. But `this` is **not** of type `MvpViewImpl`.

When you make the unsafe cast from `BaseActivity<V,P>` to `V`, you are telling the compiler `BaseActivity<V,P>` can be cast to `V`. However, the reason this works at runtime is that the compiler erases the generic type parameters `V` and `P`. Since the type bound of `V` is `MvpView`, the casting to `V` becomes a casting to `MvpView`, which `BaseActivity` implements.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed explanation. Everything that you said completely makes sense. Do you see any solution to implement this logic correctly? Is there any way to link V and BaseActivity, force them to have the same base parent interface?

Comment: @Oleksandr I don't have a suggestion at the moment. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are assuming that `V` makes reference to `BaseActivity<V,?>` because you are probably using it only this way in practice.

Unfortunately currently there is no way to make reference to the class you are declaring in the type arguments bounds as to force such a constraint.

The simplest fix is to use an unchecked cast (masking the warning if you like):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    @SupressWarning("unchecked")
    final V myView = (V) this;
    getPresenter().attachView(myView);
}
```

You don't need to use the local `myView` variable but declaring it explicitly allows you to silence only that cast and not any other "unchecked" warning in that method.

In any case you must make sure that any extending class would set their `V` type-parameter to themselves as to not break contract:

```
public class ConcreteActivity<V extends MvpView, P extends MvpPresenter<V>> extends BaseActivity<ConcreteActivity<V,P>, P> {
...
}
```

There is no way you can enforce that at compilation time, instead your test code should use reflection to verify that each extending class complies with such a restriction.

You can go a bit further in order to avoid the unchecked cast warning but that would require for you to add a field typed `V` pointing to `this` set in the BasicActivity constructor passed as a parameter by the extending class constructor....

```
public abstract class BaseActivity<V extends MvpView, P extends MvpPresenter<V>> 
        extends AppCompatActivity implements MvpView {

    private final V myView;

    protected BaseActivity(final V myView) {
       if (myView != this) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("you must pass this object"); } 
       this.myView = myView;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getPresenter().attachView(myView);
    }

    public abstract P getPresenter();

    // other logic
}


public class ConcreteActivity<V extends MvpView, P extends MvpPresenter<V> extends BaseActivity<BaseActivity<V, P>, P> {

    public ConcreteActivity() {
       super(this);
    }
    ...
}
```

Notice that we double check that `myView` is in fact `this` in the constructor in order to fail early if the extending class does not comply; you can leave that out if your test code makes sure that this is going to be always the case.

Despite that is preferable to avoid any kind of warning... I would say that in this situation the first alternative is quite acceptable as it needs less code and is more efficient memory-wise.

Comment: Thanks @valentin-ruano. I am afraid that this approach will make code less readable and I would rather go for a workaround with casting to V `getPresenter().attachView((V) this)` than forcing concrete Activity implementations to have this not obvious constructor. And in my implementation, the ConcreteActivity would implement `ConcreteView` and contain `ConcretePresenter` rather than have `BaseActivity` in generics. But again thanks for your answer.